# MySQL nested SELECT after INSERT not working (COUNT does)

Tags: mysql

I run the following INSERT statement into an InnoDB table where `group_id` is an index:

```
INSERT INTO mytbl (group_id,asset,name,price,priority) VALUES $masterInsert
```

Where `$masterInsert` is a about 1,000 rows of data with five columns (the INSERT statement works fine, just printing it here for completeness).

Immediately following the `INSERT` I want to `SELECT` the data but I want to `GROUP` by the name column and sort by priority, then price, so I write:

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE group_id='$group_id' ORDER BY priority) AS tbl GROUP BY tbl.name ORDER BY price
```

The statement above retrieves zero results, even when there are matching data. Running the following statement on the next line returns results:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytbl WHERE group_id='$group_id' GROUP BY name
```

If I switch the order around (SELECT COUNT before nested SELECT), the nested query still does not work, but the COUNT will still work.

If I immediately refresh the page, the nested SELECT works fine.

So, according to the COUNT, the data is in `mytbl`, so why is it not accessible from my nested SELECT right away?

Comment: Presumably this is because `$group_id` is not set correctly until you refresh the page.

Comment: It's obviously set correctly, as the same variable is used in the count(*) statement.